# Launching word or pdf application from my app

Tags: android, pdf, ms-word, opendocument

I wonder if some one have an example how to open a document (pdf/doc) in an external app. also rather just open it the app picker pops up with choices for their mimetype

I thought this could help in the android api DocumentsProvider ---> openDocument

But i have no idea how to implement as well as no other example i could find on the net.

So he question is simple lunch the app picker for the right type of documents , for example I pass the document path to a launcher so pdf will shows all the pdf apps installed or word docs will show the open wordoc or the ms word

**I would appreciate some example , I seen images, emails, even pdf, but i have not seen with ms word doc or docx, is anyone could help**

Comment: See: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/sending.html

Answer (score 0):

The default way for this is to issue an intent with a view-action an the URI of the pdf/doc you want to open. see [Tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_intents_filters.htm)
It is more complicated to use a document or content provider.

Comment: yes that is my point to do an email or a dialer or other stuf there are tins of example , but for the documents there are none or i could not find. but maybe morrison cheng answer could be helpful but there are lots of unanswered question.

Comment: I am still stucked guys any help would be appreciated